# Parsing invalid expressions with typescript-eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to parse an invalid expression like `f(a; b)`.

I want to get an AST for it, but it throws an error:

```js
const TSParser = require('@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree');

const parse = (code) => TSParser.parse(code, {allowInvalidAST: true});

parse('f(a; b)');
```

throws:

```
node_modules/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/dist/ast-converter.js:15
        throw (0, convert_1.convertError)(parseDiagnostics[0]);
        ^

TSError: ')' expected.
    at createError (/Users/divyansh/repos/PredScript/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/dist/node-utils.js:611:12)
    at convertError (/Users/divyansh/repos/PredScript/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/dist/convert.js:46:41)
    at astConverter (/Users/divyansh/repos/PredScript/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/dist/ast-converter.js:15:42)
    at parseWithNodeMapsInternal (/Users/divyansh/repos/PredScript/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/dist/parser.js:91:66)
```

Note that I'm also using the `allowInvalidAST` [parser option](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/typescript-estree/src/parser-options.ts).

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allowInvalidAST` only allows a limited set of invalid ASTs. From [feat(typescript-estree): added allowInvalidAST option to not throw on invalid tokens](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/6247)  *(emphasis added)*:

> It enables checks for **some known cases** where TypeScript reports a syntactic issue as semantic
>
> ...
>
> **Does not tackle more difficult cases**

Generally speaking, parsing invalid ASTs is almost always not a good idea. It's very difficult for parsers to try to piece together what users meant by invalid syntax. In this case, is it a `;` instead of a `,`, or did they miss a `)` and actually have a second syntax error on the `b)`? Impossible to say.

tl;dr: *probably* don't do this thing

Comment: I was trying to abuse the TS parser to use it to parse a different language which has a lot of similar syntax. I ended up writing a custom parser. Thanks for your reply!